# sourceAnchor selection in AADSync installation

Tags: azure, office365

sourceAnchor attribute which is mainly used to link "on premise AD object" to "azure AD object".

So it has to be unique like objectGuid. But why in installation of AADSync tool, user has the provision to change sourceAnchor to irrelevant attributes like (title, accountExpires, department, unicodePwd,.........)? Because obviously these attributes will have same value in many objects.

**What is the purpose of providing these attributes as one of the option in sourceAnchor attribute selection?**